# Why doesnt ImageView work for me? Android

Tags: java, android, view, static, imageview

My code is the following:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //landscape
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //initialize arks
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initializeArks();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Nothing special there, here comes the initializeArks():

```
    public void initializeArks(){
        iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        tw= (TypeWriter) findViewById(R.id.textView);
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(10, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

Keep in mind that this code is only for debugging, it doesnt do anything specific, but as I found out the problem is with the ImageView

Also i have my variables declared STATIC for the purpose of using them in my other classes:

```
    public static ImageView iv;
    public static TypeWriter tw;
```

My XML is a basic one:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I would be grateful if somebody explained me why this doesnt work or would send me a working code snippet for me to use for only one purpose: displaying images.

Once i install the app on my phone and open it I wait exactly 4 seconds (thats how much im delaying it by yhe code above) and it simply crashes

Comment: Don't make static variables for view types because this can lead to memory leaks, because Views hold a reference to your activity object.

Comment: what you want to do actually???

Comment: What does `doesnt work` mean? Please post your logcat.

Comment: You should properly describe your problem and not just paste your code. Also, try either setting a fixed height/width to your image view, or set `adjustViewBounds="true"` in your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt find a way to achive what I wanted so I looked in the big picture, and my scenario allowed me to not have an ImageView. Fortunately changing the layout background does the trick for me and it doesnt have any negative effects for my project. Thank you for your wasted time here

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be execute the line

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
```

inside UI thead. [Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34967039/4871526)

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your imageview in `onCreate()` method not in `initializeArks()` method and dont declare them as static like as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //landscape
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); //<==== initialise in onCreate
        tw= (TypeWriter) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //initialize arks
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initializeArks();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

And declared variable as

```
public ImageView iv;
public TypeWriter tw;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not run on the UI Thread.
Try to run inside your thread like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        initializeArks();
                    }
                });
```